# can't import a sql file

Tags: sql, import

I can't import a sql file and i don't understand why.

mysql> mysql -u root -p villes_france < villes_france.sql;

i have this error :
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p villes_france < villes_france.sql' at line 1

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you have something wrong with the syntax. Maybe you have a typo in the code. Check your file in line 1. You didn't give the code so it's hard for me and not just to search for the error.